# How can I remove multiple sub-string from a string?

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I have a `string` that looks like this:

```
string body = "<p>Dear Usr\r<br /> \r<br />See the following-\r<br /> \r<br />JN: 19\r<br />Site:  \r<br />Description: \r<br />Work Order: \r<br /> \r<br />A listing of the works completed.\r<br />Thank you .\r<br />\r<br />\r<br />\r<br /> <https://running.fielders.com/OpenEmail/ChipCo042336/email@email.com/invs-693-285> <http://email.fielders.com/wf/open?upn=ADusIqwpYMLBRw2zAWXSKaHGA8vIY6xblvtU1D07Dfl99tcMOndfzsfNIZAug7FWHwvu6euZRgdGMOicT1XrX-2BWhviOs0Ze2NWM-2FHUPwrZ5HDwgQqeiA-2BiBSIR6BsFs4pFEbmpYxQgDSEaDAZDjUJG3pPNWBCOAMhMX-2BtJ-2Baza0d-2FeipGGk1nzAI2FMUHPpU69cAr1GbPxXed-2FuQxAHEGg-3D-3D></p>"
```

Now, I want to be able to remove the two *URLs* at the end of the `string` and the "<>" tags around the *URLs*:

First one:

```
<https://running.fielders.com/OpenEmail/ChipCo042336/email@email.com/invs-693-285>
```

Second one:

```
<http://email.fielders.com/wf/open?upn=ADusIqwpYMLBRw2zAWXSKaHGA8vIY6xblvtU1D07Dfl99tcMOndfzsfNIZAug7FWHwvu6euZRgdGMOicT1XrX-2BWhviOs0Ze2NWM-2FHUPwrZ5HDwgQqeiA-2BiBSIR6BsFs4pFEbmpYxQgDSEaDAZDjUJG3pPNWBCOAMhMX-2BtJ-2Baza0d-2FeipGGk1nzAI2FMUHPpU69cAr1GbPxXed-2FuQxAHEGg-3D-3D>
```

The contents of the `string` can change, and so can the *URL* apart from the base *URLs*, which are `http://email.fielders.com` and `https://running.fielders.com` I know I need to search for those base urls, remove the `<` then delete until I hit the next `>` but I can't quite get it.

I have tried for hours playing around with this:

```
body = Regex.Replace(body, @"\s*?(?:\<http://email.fielders.com*?\>|\<https://running.fielders.com/OpenEmail/*?\>)", String.Empty);
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
var newString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"(<http://email\.fielders\.com[^>]+>|<https://running\.fielders\.com[^>]+>)", "");
```

for both URLs, match the base and all characters until a `>` is found:

```
<http://email\.fielders\.com[^>]+>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex.

```
Regex.Replace(body, @"<https?://(?:email|running)\.fielders\.com[^>]+>", "");
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/7Z70Gp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<((?:http|https):\/\/(?:email\.fielders\.com|running\.fielders\.com)(?:(?![<>]).)*)>
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kM7rT8/7